# Posting a workaround for a bug?

Tags: discussion

Background: Just recently my Ubuntu Software Center stopped working, and after a considerable amount of searching, I found the answer [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12247838&postcount=13). I thought that this is very good knowledge, so I'm considering posting it here Q&A, except that I know that this site has a strict policy about bug-related problems.

Question: Is it proper to post *workarounds* for known bugs? Or is that just as "bad" (for lack of a better word) as posting a bug report?

Comment: Just asked about couple of hours earlier. [Is it reasonable to warn people about a bug and provide a workaround?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7745)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can certainly see the usefulness of a Q&A on this but when it's a bug —and you know this is the case here— **it should definitely link into a real bug report**.

By all means reference the UF thread, but there *needs* to be something on Launchpad. Then either your question or answer should reference the official bug. This means people who also have the bug can track things back and contribute to the bug fixing process (or just follow its progress in the right place).